# JQuery App only works in IE when debugging

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

I have a website that's using a slightly modified version of Superfish that works fine in FF and Safari.

When I try it in IE 8, it doesn't work.  However, when I use an IE plugin called "Developer Tools", enable stop on error, start debugging and refresh the page, the app works.

There are a couple of errors that come up when I load the page with debugging enabled but I believe they are unrelated since the app works perfectly in FF.

Does anyone have any thoughts about why this might be occurring?

Comment: try clearing your browser history and cache in IE.

Comment: check this link
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10737299/my-application-works-in-ie-only-in-debug-mode-works-in-other-browsers

are you using console.log in your code?

Answer (score 1):

Start with fixing all errors.

Then check for "console.log()" in your code - it can produce errors in IE because it don't support it by default.