# My application works in IE only in debug mode (works in other browsers)

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

In Internet Explorer (I tried 9 and 8) my application doesn't work in the normal mode. But when I get to debug mode (press <kbd>F12</kbd>), it works with some minor problems (which are irrelevant now).

This makes it impossible for me to debug my application, because in debug mode, it just starts working.

This is [the application I developed](http://games.ourcity-sy.com).

What could be the solution?

Comment: need to know problem, before can find solution

Comment: the problem is that it doesn't work in Internet Explorer

Comment: Well on that basis, then the solution is to not use Internet Explorer. My point is, you cant just give us a website link and expect us to test, debug and fix it for you. You need to try and identify the problem (check for javascript errors) and come back with a more specific problem

Comment: @musefan
ok, I just want to have this first clue, I forgot the console.log issue with IE, I really tried for hours to figure it out, but as I said, when I get to debug mode it works, so this confuses me from know the real reason,

thx anyway for your comment

Comment: I think this is a real question, and could help future visitors. Should not be closed.

Comment: A life saver.. Maybe the question isn't constructed right, but it led me to the solution.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Do you use `console.log` in your script?
In IE browsers `console` object exists in scope only in debug mode.
Change your code to:

```
if (console) console.log('...')
```

EDIT: I've looked at your application and you are using console log.

Comment: +1 - but have generally found that `if (variable)` can be problematic, so tend to recommend using `if typeof(variable) != "undefined"`

Comment: thanks it worked fine, I will work on minor things now :)

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the issue. I used if(window.console)...  if(console) was not working.

Comment: wow worked for me...saved me a lot of time : )

Comment: wow, what a stupid bug in IE

Comment: Gee, for a question that is too "localized", this really helped me.