# datatable editable is having issue with IE

Tags: jquery, datatables, jeditable, spservices

I am working on SharePoint 2010 with spservices, datatable, jeditable and datatable.editable. My version of the frameworks are as follows

1. IE 9, 10, 11
2. jQuery 1.7.2
3. spservices 2013.01
4. datatable 1.9.4
5. datatable editable 2.3.3
6. jedittable N/A

Now issue is editing of datatabale is working good in FireFox and Chrome but it is not working in IE when I blur from element it is not disappearing.

My code is as follows

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/sites/MS/Style%20Library/en-us/CSS/forms-simple.css"/>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="/sites/ms/Style%20Library/en-us/JS/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/sites/ms/Style%20Library/en-us/JS/jquery.SPServices-2013.01.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="/sites/ms/Style%20Library/MarketSurveillance.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/sites/MS/Style%20Library/ar-sa/JS/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="/sites/MS/Style%20Library/en-us/JS/jquery.jeditable.mini.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/sites/MS/Style%20Library/en-us/JS/jquery.dataTables.editable.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function () {
var oTable, anOpen = [], sImageUrl = "/sites/MS/Style%20Library/Images/", sInner;
var viewFields = "<FieldRef Name='ID' /><FieldRef Name='Title' /><FieldRef Name='TelephoneNo' /><FieldRef Name='PlaceOfProduct' />";
viewFields += "<FieldRef Name='CategoryID' /><FieldRef Name='SubCategoryID' /><FieldRef Name='Status' />";
populateGrid("/sites/ms/", "ComplaintForm", viewFields, "", handleData);

oTable = $("#tbComplaintForm").dataTable({
  "bProcessing": true,
  "aoColumns": [
     {
       "bSortable": false,
       "mDataProp": null,
       "mData": null,
       "sClass": "control center",
       "sDefaultContent": '<img src="' + sImageUrl + 'details_open.png">'
     },
    null ,
    null ,
    null ,
    null ,
    null ,
    null
  ]
});

oTable.makeEditable({
  "aoColumns": [
    null, null, null, null, null, null,
    {
      "sName": "Status",
      "indicator": "Approve/Reject Complaint Status",
      "tooltip": "Approve/Reject",
      "loadtext": "loading...",
      "type": "select",
      "onblur": "submit",
      "data": "{'0':' ', '3':'Approved','4':'Rejected'}",
      "sUpdateURL": function (value, settings) {
        var columnId = oTable.fnGetPosition(this)[2];
        var dataArray = [];
        dataArray.push([oTable.fnSettings().aoColumns[columnId].sTitle, value]);
        itemOperation("/sites/ms/", "ComplaintForm", "Update", dataArray, $(this).closest('tr').attr('id'));
        return value;
      }
    }
  ],
  "oEditableSettings": { event: 'click' }
});

$('#tbComplaintForm td.control').live('click', function () {
  var nTr = this.parentNode;
  var i = $.inArray(nTr, anOpen);

  if (i === -1) {
    $('img', this).attr('src', sImageUrl + "details_close.png");
    var nDetailsRow = oTable.fnOpen(nTr, fnFormatDetails(oTable, nTr), 'details');
    $('div.innerDetails', nDetailsRow).slideDown();
    anOpen.push(nTr);
  }
  else {
    $('img', this).attr('src', sImageUrl + "details_open.png");
    $('div.innerDetails', $(nTr).next()[0]).slideUp(function () {
      oTable.fnClose(nTr);
      anOpen.splice(i, 1);
    });
  }
  });
 });

   function fnFormatDetails(oTable, nTr) {
var oData = oTable.fnGetData(nTr);
var _viewFields = "<FieldRef Name='Comments' /><FieldRef Name='Suggestions' />";
var qry = "<Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name=\"ID\" /><Value Type=\"Counter\">" + $(nTr).attr('id') + "</Value></Eq></Where></Query>";
populateGrid("/sites/ms/", "ComplaintForm", _viewFields, qry, innerData);
var sOut = sInner;
return sOut;
}

  function innerData(xData, Status) {
sInner = "";
sInner += '<div class="innerDetails"><table cellpadding="7" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="padding-left:75px;">';
if (Status == "success") {
  $(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("z:row").each(function () {
    sInner += '<tr><td>Comment:</td><td>' + $(this).attr("ows_Comments") + '</td></tr>';
    sInner += '<tr><td>Suggestions:</td><td>' + $(this).attr("ows_Suggestions") + '</td></tr>';
  });
}
sInner += '</table></div>';
 }

  function handleData(xData, Status) {
var datarows = "<tbody>";
var query = "";
if (Status == "success") {
  $(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("z:row").each(function () {
    datarows += "<tr id=" + $(this).attr("ows_ID") + "><td class='read_only'></td><td>" + $(this).attr("ows_Title") + "</td>";
    datarows += "<td>" + $(this).attr("ows_TelephoneNo") + "</td>";
    query = "<Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name=\"ID\" /><Value Type=\"Text\">" + $(this).attr("ows_CategoryID").replace(".00000000000000", "") + "</Value></Eq></Where></Query>";
    datarows += "<td>" + getSingleItem("http://sp2010-base", "SAS_Categories", "Category_Title_EN", query) + "</td>";
    query = "<Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name=\"ID\" /><Value Type=\"Text\">" + $(this).attr("ows_SubCategoryID").replace(".00000000000000", "") + "</Value></Eq></Where></Query>";
    datarows += "<td>" + getSingleItem("http://sp2010-base", "SAS_SubCategories", "Sub_Category_Title_EN", query) + "</td>";
    datarows += "<td>" + $(this).attr("ows_PlaceOfProduct") + "</td>";
    if ($(this).attr("ows_Status") == 0)
      datarows += "<td></td></tr>";
    else if ($(this).attr("ows_Status") == 1)
      datarows += "<td>In Plane</td></tr>";
    else if ($(this).attr("ows_Status") == 2)
      datarows += "<td>Checked</td></tr>";
    else if ($(this).attr("ows_Status") == 3)
      datarows += "<td>Approved</td></tr>";
    else if ($(this).attr("ows_Status") == 4)
      datarows += "<td>Rejected</td></tr>";
  });
  datarows += "</tbody>";
  $("#tbComplaintForm").append(datarows);
}
}
```

Complaint Name
            Telephone No.
            Category
            SubCategory 
            Place Of Product
            Status

So what can be issue with IE

Comment: which version of IE you are using?

Comment: Kindly check my answer as edited.

Comment: @Milind would it be possible for you to recreate a small example in JSFiddle?

Comment: @Danny as it involves SharePoint and it is on my VM, I cannot do JSFiddle. But I can add some more detail. I am using "sUpdateURL" and in that function I am not doing server side update but I am calling again client side function which uses spservices to update my data into the list and as per the documentation of jeditable it should be server side, but again it is working in chrome and FireFox but not in IE. May be I am wrong about "sUpdateURL"

Comment: Today I found very funny thing today, I am in IE 11 and when I console window and try to update and click out side drop down will go away, which is we need but as I close console window it stop working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may not be the answer you need, but according to your last comment, It looks like you have code that successfully works when IE's JavaScript debugger is running but not normally. This can be due to any console.log's or other kinds of "debugger only js code". Here is a possible answer to your issue: [My application works in IE only in debug mode (works in other browsers)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10737299/my-application-works-in-ie-only-in-debug-mode-works-in-other-browsers)